# gcp suspending active libvirt guests

Tags: kvm-virtualization, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, ubuntu-16.04, libvirt-guests

I am facing the issue where GCP is suspending all the active libvirt guests frequently. Below are the logs from syslog.

google-clock-skew: INFO Synced system time with hardware clock.
 systemd[1]: Started Virtualization daemon.
 systemd[1]: Starting Suspend Active Libvirt Guests...
 snapd[1422]: daemon.go:611: gracefully waiting for running hooks
 snapd[1422]: daemon.go:613: done waiting for running hooks
 snapd[1422]: daemon stop requested to wait for socket activation
 systemd[1]: Started Suspend Active Libvirt Guests.

Comment: I believe that the error you want to bring attention to is 'systemd[1]: Starting Suspend Active Libvirt Guests...'
"[systemd](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/systemd) is a system and session manager for Linux" the issue seems to be an OS issue which is related to Linux and therefore not managed by GCP. Could you indicate why you believe this to be a GCP issue?

Comment: I am seeing some of the GCP processes are running in the syslog before Suspending Active Libvirt Guests. GCP is trying to start them again using the startup-script if mentioned in the metadata file. As there is no metadata file, the VMs are not starting and we need to start them manually.

Comment: Could you please be more specific? I am not sure how this is connected with GCP. Is your GCE VM not starting or  Libvirt Guests services?

Comment: My VMs are going down,I am suspecting that google-shutdown-scripts.service is suspending the active libvirt guests as they are going down when this scripts are running. I am not sure though, just guessing. Any help would be appreciated here. Below are the services enabled.

google-accounts-daemon.service             enabled 
google-clock-skew-daemon.service           enabled 
google-instance-setup.service              enabled 
google-network-daemon.service              enabled 
google-shutdown-scripts.service            enabled 
google-startup-scripts.service             enabled

Comment: I have disabled google-shutdown-scripts.service. Still Same issue. Complete log is here.https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/qWpqp4q9SGS0NIpIyWaV

Appreciate any help here.

Comment: After doing log inspection, there are a number of error messages in the logs that could have caused the issue. I would suggest to re-install libvirt-daemon-system deb package that may resolve the issue:
=> sudo apt-get install libvirt-daemon-system

Comment: Still same issue after re-install. I have also done the fresh installation with 16.04 and 18.04. Same issue on both of them as well. Not sure what to check further to avoid this automatic suspension of libvirt-guests.